# Remove all file except multiple file by command

Tags: command-line, regex

I have multiple file on my Ubuntu directory. I want to use a terminal command to delete all files except the files that are generated today.

Today is 2019-10-15 and my files are:

```
...
field_20191012152850.php
field_20191013022128.php
field_20191014095433.php
field_20191015101257.php
```

The file names contain 4 sections. First section is `field_`, second part is date (e.g. `20191014` = 2019-10-14), third part is time (e.g. `231241` = 23:12:41) and Fourth part is `.php`.

We can remove those files by file info, e.g. file generation datetime or by file name e.g. `field_20191014095433.php`.

I can remove today's files with the following command:

```
rm field_$(date +%Y%m%d)[0-9]{6}.php
```

But I want to remove all files except today's files by file generation info or file name. We can also use the bash file instead of a one-line command.

Comment: You should have searched properly before posting https://www.vionblog.com/linux-delete-files-older-than-x-days/

Comment: @SachinYadav Thanks. I did searching, but probably not a good search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `find`:

```
find /path/to/folder -type f -not -name "field_$(date +%Y%m%d)*.php" -delete
```

This will recursively search `/path/to/folder` for the matching files.

If you only need find to find files in `/path/to/folder`, without searching in its subdirectories, just add the `-maxdepth -1` flag:

```
find /path/to/folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name "field_$(date +%Y%m%d)*.php" -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extglob` to exclude pattern:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm field_!($(date +%Y%m%d)*).php
```

You might want to turn off extglob afterwards using `shopt -u extglob`.

[See also](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164025/exclude-one-pattern-from-glob-match)